# CSS selector on an attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a bunch of inputs e.g:

```
<div class="token-list">
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[]" value="token1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens_text[]" value="token1_text" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[]" value="token2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens_text[]" value="token2_text" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[]" value="token3" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens_text[]" value="token3_text" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[]" value="token4" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens_text[]" value="token4_text" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens[]" value="token5" />
  <input type="hidden" name="tokens_text[]" value="token5_text" />
</div>
```

Is it possible to select just the ones with the name 'tokens' in CSS?

I was hoping to do something like `input[name~=hosts[]]` (This isn't working - I assume because of the square brackets in the name).

Comment: if it's the real html you can try :nth-child(2n) or why not :odd or :even

Comment: +1 for :nth-child(2n) but this won't work for me - This is a snippet of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[name="tokens[]"] {
    background: honeydew;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2pUgY/3/

Comment: Attribute selectors are awesome. I've found Chris Coyier's [post](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) on them to be invaluable.